# Pattern occurred 0 or 1 time

Tags: regex

How do I use regex to check if a pattern only occured **at most 1 time** in a string?

For example, if I am checking for the pattern `name=`:

- `key=value` = True
- `key=value&name=something` = True
- `key=value&name=&name=something` = False

Note:

- The string need not to be URL like. The aboves are just example.
- There is no specific delimiter for the pattern.

I know that `^((?!name=).)*$` could check for 0 occurence of the pattern, but I am not sure how to continue from there.

Comment: `{1,}` is just a really clumsy way to write `+`; but that is incorrect, it looks for one or more, not zero or one.

Comment: Didn't see *"at most 1"*

Comment: Do you really require regex for this though? A better solution would be to parse the URL tail (I assume this is?) and check whether the key is unique.

Comment: @tripleee the URL liked string is just an example.

Comment: That only makes this more vague, and the suggestion still holds; parse whatever this is, and check the number of occurrences of the keys you care about. Could the separator be something else than `&` (or, I still presume, `?`)?

Comment: Still the question remains. Regex solution appears complex, if it even exists. Must you use regex?

Answer (score 0):

if it's possible to separate each key/values pairs with the `&` char (assuming that's an URL), i can suggest this solution:

```regex
/^[^&\s]*?(?:[^&\s]+(?<!name)=[^&\s]*?&)*?(name=[^&\s]+)?(?:&[^&\s]+(?<!name)=[^&\s]*?)*?[^&\s]*?$/gm
```

The three parts of the regex are:

- `[^&\s]*?(?:[^&\s]+(?<!name)=[^&\s]*?&)*?` which match everything before name and without name
- `(name=[^&\s]+)?` which capture name=some_value if one
- `(?:&[^&\s]+(?<!name)=[^&\s]*?)*?[^&\s]*?` which match everything after name and without name